# Optimize if this code?

Tags: java, performance

I need to improve this code, is very heavy and I did not find another way to create

that all conditions need to be verified, not important if a condition is true, has to keep looking for the other conditions.

use sorry for my english GoogleTranslate

```
if (skill.getId() == 233 && getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 96) {
    removeSkillById(233); // Light Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 227 && getActiveClassId() == 36 || getActiveClassId() == 9 || getActiveClassId() == 37 || getActiveClassId() == 23 || getActiveClassId() == 24 || getActiveClassId() == 8 || getActiveClassId() == 48 || getActiveClassId() == 108 || getActiveClassId() == 92 || getActiveClassId() == 109 || getActiveClassId() == 101 || getActiveClassId() == 102 || getActiveClassId() == 93 || getActiveClassId() == 114 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 96) {
    removeSkillById(227); // Light Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 236 && getActiveClassId() == 36 || getActiveClassId() == 9 || getActiveClassId() == 37 || getActiveClassId() == 23 || getActiveClassId() == 24 || getActiveClassId() == 8 || getActiveClassId() == 48 || getActiveClassId() == 108 || getActiveClassId() == 92 || getActiveClassId() == 109 || getActiveClassId() == 101 || getActiveClassId() == 102 || getActiveClassId() == 93 || getActiveClassId() == 114 || getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 96) {
    removeSkillById(236); // Light Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 252 && getActiveClassId() == 36 || getActiveClassId() == 9 || getActiveClassId() == 37 || getActiveClassId() == 23 || getActiveClassId() == 24 || getActiveClassId() == 8 || getActiveClassId() == 48 || getActiveClassId() == 108 || getActiveClassId() == 92 || getActiveClassId() == 109 || getActiveClassId() == 101 || getActiveClassId() == 102 || getActiveClassId() == 93 || getActiveClassId() == 114 || getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 96) {
    removeSkillById(252); // Light Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 258 && getActiveClassId() == 36 || getActiveClassId() == 9 || getActiveClassId() == 37 || getActiveClassId() == 23 || getActiveClassId() == 24 || getActiveClassId() == 8 || getActiveClassId() == 48 || getActiveClassId() == 108 || getActiveClassId() == 92 || getActiveClassId() == 109 || getActiveClassId() == 101 || getActiveClassId() == 102 || getActiveClassId() == 93 || getActiveClassId() == 114 || getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116) {
    removeSkillById(258); // Light Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 231 && getActiveClassId() == 6 || getActiveClassId() == 5 || getActiveClassId() == 33 || getActiveClassId() == 20 || getActiveClassId() == 91 || getActiveClassId() == 90 || getActiveClassId() == 106 || getActiveClassId() == 99 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 98) {
    removeSkillById(231); // Heavy Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 232 && getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 98) {
    removeSkillById(232); // Heavy Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 253 && getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 6 || getActiveClassId() == 5 || getActiveClassId() == 33 || getActiveClassId() == 20 || getActiveClassId() == 91 || getActiveClassId() == 90 || getActiveClassId() == 106 || getActiveClassId() == 99 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 98) {
    removeSkillById(253); // Heavy Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 259 && getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 6 || getActiveClassId() == 5 || getActiveClassId() == 33 || getActiveClassId() == 20 || getActiveClassId() == 91 || getActiveClassId() == 90 || getActiveClassId() == 106 || getActiveClassId() == 99 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116) {
    removeSkillById(259); // Heavy Armor
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 234 && getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116) {
    removeSkillById(234); // Robe Mastery
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 235 && getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 13 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 12 || getActiveClassId() == 40 || getActiveClassId() == 27 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 95 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 94 || getActiveClassId() == 110 || getActiveClassId() == 103 || getActiveClassId() == 96 || getActiveClassId() == 51 || getActiveClassId() == 52 || getActiveClassId() == 115 || getActiveClassId() == 116) {
    removeSkillById(235); // Robe Mastery
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
if (skill.getId() == 251 && getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 13 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 12 || getActiveClassId() == 40 || getActiveClassId() == 27 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 95 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 94 || getActiveClassId() == 110 || getActiveClassId() == 103 || getActiveClassId() == 96 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 112) {
    removeSkillById(251); // Robe Mastery
} else {
    // Nothing...
}
```

any help me? thanks!!

Comment: you can remove the `else { }` statements

Comment: You'll probably gain some performance (and clarity) by computing `skill.getId()` and `getActiveClassId()`, etc. once before the big `if` outside. Think about using a `switch` on `skill.getId()` instead of the nested `if`s, and just handle the rest of the conditions. Or do it the OO-way: Make each object handle its part of the logic, don't handle it outside (will probably mean a complete redesign of the class hierarchy...).

Comment: You should really look into [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of all those magic numbers.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using magic numbers to store discrete types. Java has enums and constants.

Comment: Whatever this is changed too the performance is going to be so negligible. Perhaps you mean refactor not optimize? Personally I think your wasting your time as its very unlikely this is a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a couple of things to optimize this.

1. Remove the following code blocks, they're unnecessary:

   ```
   else 
   {
       // Nothing..
   }
   ```
2. Next, save the return value from your functions to local variables to save the overhead of calling the same function many, many times.

   ```
   int activeClassId = getActiveClassId(), skillId = skill.getId();
   ```
3. Use a `List` to store the possible values, and use `List.contains()`. For example, you can now transform this:

   ```
   if(skill.getId() == 252 && getActiveClassId() == 36 || getActiveClassId() == 9 || getActiveClassId() == 37 || getActiveClassId() == 23 || getActiveClassId() == 24 || getActiveClassId() == 8 || getActiveClassId() == 48 || getActiveClassId() == 108 || getActiveClassId() == 92 || getActiveClassId() == 109 || getActiveClassId() == 101 || getActiveClassId() == 102 || getActiveClassId() == 93 || getActiveClassId() == 114 || getActiveClassId() == 55 || getActiveClassId() == 46 || getActiveClassId() == 2 || getActiveClassId() == 3 || getActiveClassId() == 57 || getActiveClassId() == 117 || getActiveClassId() == 113 || getActiveClassId() == 88 || getActiveClassId() == 89 || getActiveClassId() == 118 || getActiveClassId() == 16 || getActiveClassId() == 30 || getActiveClassId() == 17 || getActiveClassId() == 43 || getActiveClassId() == 97 || getActiveClassId() == 105 || getActiveClassId() == 98 || getActiveClassId() == 112 || getActiveClassId() == 28 || getActiveClassId() == 41 || getActiveClassId() == 14 || getActiveClassId() == 104 || getActiveClassId() == 111 || getActiveClassId() == 96)
   ```

   Into this:

   ```
   List<Integer> validClassIds = Arrays.asList( 36, 9, 37, 23, 24, 8, 48, 108, 92, 109, 101, 102, 93, 114, 55, 46, 2, 3, 57, 117, 113, 88, 89, 118, 16, 30, 17, 43, 97, 105, 98, 112, 28, 41, 14, 104, 111, 96);

   if( skillId == 252 && validClassIds.contains( activeClassId))
   ```

If you don't want to do an `O(n)` search with `List.contains()`, you can use a HashSet instead of a List. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558978/most-efficient-way-to-see-if-an-arraylist-contains-an-object-in-java).

Comment: I highly doubt any data structure is going to perform any better than what he has. I don't blame you... this is a terrible question.

Comment: @Adam For the overall application, it depends. But it is currently calling the same function 292 times, definitely inefficient.

Comment: So you know exactly how the JIT optimizes? With out benchmarks you definitely cannot assume anything.

Comment: @Adam Prove me wrong. It's basic programming principles, there's no assumptions being made.

Comment: @nickb why don't you try it yourself. Unless this is not a regular getter the jvm will optimize for this case. Run it millions of times and I doubt you will see performance difference particular since java has a warm up time that is very unpredictable. Your also asinine in saying this is basic programming principle. Functions or even more so macros can be faster particular in a non eager language like Haskell.

Comment: @nickb Your offering optimization recommendations such as using a O(n) data structure for a micro benchmarking question. The correct answer/suggestion is to go benchmark. I say "doubt" instead of saying "definitely" because if you *actually* benchmark you will get different results. Also I just tried to benchmark and surprise surprise the results vary wildly and about %50 the time the getter was faster. Why... because vtable access is negligible to say a branch misprediction.

Answer (score 1):

I have advice from algorithm perspective.

Use **[Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)** to minimize the compare times by adjust if-else conditions sequence.if you have statistic of possibility of data.