# Check if an ArrayList contains a given object

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Assuming I have class like this:

```
class A {
  int elementA;
  int elementB
}
```

I also have an `ArrayList` like this: `ArrayList<A> listObj`.

How can I check if that list contains an object using only some of the  properties of `A`? E.g. considering only `elementA` for finding if object `newA{elementA}` is already in the list?

For object `A` I have defined an `equals` method, where I consider only the `elementA`, however this is not enough.

Comment: Show your `equals` method.

Comment: If you have overridden your equals() correctly, then listObj.contains(new A(elemAvalue)) should work. Note that you should also override hashCode only considering elementA value, though it's not functionally relevant for this example.

Comment: `if (!days.contains(getDate())) {

        days.add(getDate());

}`

Comment: for equals i use [here is example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.dk/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)  as source (equals and hashCode)

Answer (score 33):

[List#contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method uses the `equals()` method to evaluate if two objects are the same. So, you need to override `equals()` in your Class `A` and also override the `hashCode()`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    boolean isEqual= false;

    if (object != null && object instanceof A)
    {
        isEqual = (this.elementA == ((A) object).elementA);
    }

    return isEqual;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.elementA;
}
```

Comment: This works fine as long as you have to compare the A elements, but as soon as the requirement changes you can throw this out, not to mention that you might want to use the equals or hashcode methods other places, I would go with a Comparator thats for sure.

Comment: Fair enough! But List `contains()` uses the `equals` method, not `Comparable.compareTo()` !

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
For newbies like me: If `elementA` is `String` type, then use `isEqual = (this.elementA.equals(((A) object).elementA));`

Comment: In case "elementA" is a String, we need not override hashCode() method

Answer (score 4):

You could adapt your `equals` to accomodate for your needs, but you could also use one of the powerful collection libraries that already exists, like [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). They all have iteration and predicate constructs that allow you to "explore" your collections based on some predicate.

Example with Commons Collections:

```
boolean contains = CollectionUtils.exists(myArrayList, new Predicate<A>() {
    public boolean evaluate(A theA) {
        // Do the comparison
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't override `equals` for this. Even though `{1, 1}` and `{1, 2}` cannot both occur in your list, the two objects are *not* equal.

I would use a `Map` instead:

```
Map<Integer, A> map = new HashMap<>();
A a1 = new A(1, 1);
A a2 = new A(1, 2);

map.put(a1.elementA, a1);

// test if key is contained
boolean contains = map.containsKey(a2.elementA);

// overwrite a1 with a2
map.put(a2.elementA, a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hashCode()` and `equals()` of arrays are a bit broken when it comes to this (it is a long different discussion why).

A possible work around is to use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` instead of `ArrayList<String[]>`, the equals() method for ArrayList will be as you expect it to.

For example:

```
   ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add("asdf");
    l2.add("asdf");
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> coll = new ArrayList<>();
    coll.add(l1);
    System.out.println(coll.contains(l2));
```

Will yield true, as expected

Also refer below link

[Most efficient way to see if an ArrayList contains an object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558978/most-efficient-way-to-see-if-an-arraylist-contains-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

All the above solution will suits your question. 
What i like to suggest you here is !!!
When ever you use collection, always have your variable datatype to its super class. which will help you to make more manipulation and convert to any of its sub-class.

```
Ex:
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The advantage that the implementation of the List can change (to a LinkedList for example), without affecting the rest of the code. This is will be difficult to do with an ArrayList, not only because you will need to change ArrayList to LinkedList everywhere, but also because you may have used ArrayList specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing the object value in `arrayList`.
Follow this Link.
[How to compare Objects attributes in an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408850/how-to-compare-objects-attributes-in-an-arraylist/48300092#48300092)

I hope this solution will help you.
Thanks

Comment: This should not be set as an answer I guess, but as a comment.

Comment: You cannot just link to answer. You have to give the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Upload> mUploadPost = new ArrayList<Upload>();
Upload upload = new Upload();
upload.addName("Mpendulo");
upload.addLastName("Mtshali");
if(!mUploadPost.contains(upload)){
    mUploadPost.add(upload);
}
```