# How to check Object ArrayList contain single attribute of Object without Loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, search, arraylist

[Here is the answer of this  question but I need is there any other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408850/how-to-compare-objects-attributes-in-an-arraylist)

Let Suppose Person is a class contains attribute

- personId
- personName
- personAddress

An ArrayList hold thousand person object ,I want to check that "11" personId  is in ArayList or not?

One way is to iterate(Loop) arraylist and check single by single.

Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, create a second `Set` of `personId` to test against or simulate a database index by creating an additional `Map` of `personId` to `person`.

Comment: You could build a `HashMap<Integer, Person>` where Integer is `Person.personId` and then use simple get: `get(id) == null`.

Comment: can you show me some sample but remember I am using Java and I need to only use ArrayList not HashMap or some other collections.

Comment: If you use only an ArrayList there is no way around looping through it, either implicitely or explicitely. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to check 11 personId is in  thousand person objects in arraylist or not ?
I know there is contain() in arraylist but this compare whole person object but only presonId attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override equals() and hashcode() method in your POJO for person Id

eg:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
private int personId;
private String name;
//getters and Setters



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + personId;
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
       return true;
    if (obj == null)
       return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
       return false;
    Test other = (Test) obj;
    if (personId != other.personId)
       return false;
    return true;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Test> test=new ArrayList<Test>();

Test t=new Test();
t.setName("Sireesh");
t.setPersonId(1);

Test t1=new Test();
t1.setName("Ramesh");
t1.setPersonId(2);

Test t2=new Test();
t2.setName("Rajesh");
t2.setPersonId(3);


test.add(t);
test.add(t1);
test.add(t2);

Test tx=new Test();
tx.setPersonId(1);
System.out.println(test.contains(tx));
//Returns true

}
}
```

Comment: @YasirShabbirChoudhary No, it isn't if you're using only `List`s. However, it is good practice to override both `hashCode()` and `equals()` in order to satisfy these operations contract, otherwise some Java collections wouldn't work as expected, i.e. if you used a `HashSet` you would run into trouble. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `equals` and `hashCode` based on `persionId`. `java.util.ArrayList#contains` will give you results. This solution is as good as looping through list and finding the object.