# Why onChildAdded is fired multiple times?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my code, I don't know if I get it because of onChildAdded or RecyclerView

**Simply** I want to display messages Inbox on RecyclerView that contains all messages I received from other users, each message contains the last message sent and information about senders such as his name and photo.

**Like this**

[image]

This is my structure

```
Messages
  Receiver_UID
     Sender_UID
        push 
          message : "text"
```

I used 2 nested query to achieve that 
so firstly I get sender UID, and then I get the last message from another query

```
dataQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id);
    dataQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot getalldata, String s) {

            final String sender_UID = getalldata.getKey();

            Query lastmess = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id).child(sendUID);
            lastmess.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { // last message
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snap, String s) {
                    MessModel messages = snap.getValue(MessModel.class);
                    String Last_message = messages.getMessage();
                    getUserData(Last_message ,sender_UID);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**And finally** I get information of sender by this method

```
private void getUserData(final String last_message , String sendUID) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByKey().equalTo(sendUID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot data, final String s) {

            listImessagesitem model = data.getValue(listImessagesitem.class);
            name =model.getName();
            uid = model.getUid();
            //another information

            result.add( new listImessagesitem( name ,last_message ,uid, ... another info));
            useradapter = new listMessagesAdapter(getActivity(),result);
            myList.setAdapter(useradapter);
            useradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        }

    });
}
```

It works well the first time and when I make refresh as well

**The problem is** when someone, in the list of messages Inbox, sends me a new message. In this case, if I didn't make refresh, I see two senders with the same information and different last messages ... If he sent again, I see 3 senders with same previous case and so on.

How can I fix it?

I mean How can I add the new message to the user if he already exists in my inbox list

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from looking at your code is that u have nested ChildEventListener's. So every-time the top listener is invoked a new inner child listener is created causing duplicate data as it calls the getUserData method to update the adapter.

What you can do?

1: Check if the result list contains the object if not then add otherwise ignore.

2: From what I understand, I believe you are trying to create a Mail Client application where two users are sending emails to each other. So instead of the structure that you have in your db why not create a single node for both the users something like this **user_1_ID+user_2_ID** .

This reduces the complexity as both the users will read from the same node and the message object should have a timestamp field to determine the latest message.

Comment: Thanks for help , I already tried to do your first point but it is failed .. can you give me some code about How to check  if the result list contains the object or not , and how I can ignore it ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16273310/5065318 check this question on how u can implement that.