# Efficient string searching in Java

Tags: java, string, performance, search, processing-efficiency

I am working with two big lists of data and I need to efficiently check for matches between the two. This is the scenario:

- Reading from a file line by line (this file has 1 million lines)
- For each line, check within an ArrayList of strings whether it has a match (this ArrayList also has a huge number of elements)
- If a match is found, replace the line from the file with a new value

Any ideas what would be a good way to tackle this problem in terms of efficiency? Obviously looping through that number of records is hopelessly inefficient and process heavy.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**
It's worth noting, I'm not specifically saying I *need* to use an ArrayList, that is just something I was using for testing. Any suggestions of more efficient Collections would be welcome.

Comment: Not a duplicate or anything, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559056/2375907) could be helpful

Comment: Why do you use an ArrayList to check for matches? Wouldn't it be better to use a HashSet instead?

Comment: What does "match" mean in your context? `fileLine.equals(collectionElement)` ?

Comment: As Ralf Renz says use a hashMap for the second list. Then it will be O(N) time to check all matches. Also if the first list is a set(no repeated values) then you could remove the values in hashMap that you already matched. I am also assuming you are not checking matches for the new value, are you?

Comment: It depends whether you can parse the lines into words or you want a generic approach supporting any string (not necessarily limited by word borders). The first is best done with a word index (Bloomfilter, Hashmap, Trie), the second with a multistring matching algorithm (e.g. Aho-Corasick).

Comment: The file line will be someting like "item1" and I will be checking an ArrayList (or any other type of list) against each line looking for the match.

Comment: But does "match" mean equality, i.e. do you just test if the input line is exactly equal to some member of your ArrayList? If so, then a `HashSet` trivially solves it. If you need a case-insensitive match, it's still simple. If you match by common words or alike, then it may get much more complicated. Pls, add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider reading the file partially by different threads.
Similar issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037404/java-read-large-text-file-with-70million-line-of-text).

You may process the text in chunks (say x bytes or one line) , each chunk can be executed by different threads , ie one thread per chunk.

Comment: The reference points to reading large files not to searching in large files.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details (such as the nature of the keys) it is difficult to be certain but you may find using a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) useful to minimise the number of times you do `check within an ArrayList of strings whether it has a match`.

Obviously this would not help much if the lookup list changes over time.

You would use the Bloom filter to do a pre-check before searching the list because it can very quickly give you a straight `no` answer if the key does not exist in the list. You will still need to search you list if the bloom filter says `maybe`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use HashMap it's approximately O(1), or if your strings have a lot of collisions than you need to use TreeSet O(logN), or Bloom filter.

Comment: HashSet organizes buckets as trees if there are many collisions since Java 8

Comment: that's true, but just TreeSet will be faster than HashMap+TreeSet.