# How to generate a unique hash code for string input in android...?

Tags: java, android, hash, hashmap

I wanted to generate a unique hash code for a string in put in android.
Is there any predefined library is there or we have to generate manually. Please any body if knows please present a link or a code stuff.

Comment: What about built-in hashCode for Strings?

Comment: unique hash code? why? and how do you even think that's possible?

Comment: Please elaborate. Unique hash codes are impossible (unless they can have an infinite length), since there is an infinity of possible strings.

Comment: That is totally wrong. I can think of five ways to create a unique hash code just off the top of my head. It all starts with overriding the hashCode () function. Anyway, the last comment is a bit of an oversimplification: If a hash is created on a large enough domain with a robust generator, the chances of a collision can be extremely small. IFF you override hashCode to use a thread-safe incrementor, you can have unique values. Most of the time, though, when implemented correctly, it just *does not matter* probability-wise.

Comment: @ingyhere - Please show us how ...

Comment: @Stephen C - An earlier comment was surely deleted in the two years before your followup. More importantly, though, context is key: This isn't the Crypto board. You missed the part about "it does not matter probability wise" and in this context unique means 'effectively unique'. But think about it: There is an easy way to check for collisions in a self-contained system.

Comment: You have no idea what the OP's context is.  Absolutely no idea.  Assuming that when he says "unique" that he doesn't mean that is a huge stretch.  Anyhow, the challenge remains:  Show us how.

Answer (score 65):

It depends on what you mean:

- As mentioned `String.hashCode()` gives you a 32 bit hash code.
- If you want (say) a 64-bit hashcode you can easily implement it yourself.
- If you want a cryptographic hash of a String, the Java crypto libraries include implementations of MD5, SHA-1 and so on.  You'll typically need to turn the String into a byte array, and then feed that to the hash generator / digest generator.  For example, see @Bryan Kemp's answer.
- If you want a **guaranteed unique** hash code, you are out of luck.  Hashes and hash codes are non-unique.

A Java String of length N has `65536 ^ N` possible states, and requires an integer with `16 * N` bits to represent all possible values.  If you write a hash function that produces integer with a smaller range (e.g. less than `16 * N` bits), you will eventually find cases where more than one String hashes to the same integer; i.e. the hash codes cannot be unique.  This is called the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), and there is a straight forward mathematical proof.  (You can't fight math and win!)

But if "probably unique" with a very small chance of non-uniqueness is acceptable, then crypto hashes are a good answer.  The math will tell you how big (i.e. how many bits) the hash has to be to achieve a given (low enough) probability of non-uniqueness.

Comment: 64-bit hashcode: for completeness if you want a 64-bit one, from sfussenegger in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660501/what-is-a-good-64bit-hash-function-in-java-for-textual-strings

Comment: So, a 32-bit hash can only uniquely identify a String with 2 characters?

Comment: Basically ... yes.  (Assuming character == arbitrary `char` value.  It gets a bit more complicated if character means Unicode codepoint ... or (say) ASCII codepoint.)

Answer (score 39):

This is a class I use to create Message Digest hashes

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Sha1Hex {

    public String makeSHA1Hash(String input)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            md.reset();
            byte[] buffer = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
            md.update(buffer);
            byte[] digest = md.digest();

            String hexStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
                hexStr +=  Integer.toString( ( digest[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
            }
            return hexStr;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
String input = "some input string";
int hashCode = input.hashCode();
System.out.println("input hash code = " + hashCode);
```

Comment: @Vladimir - by definition no hash code is defined to be unique! Hashcode needs to be well distributed, uniqueness idea is a faulty understanding of the OP.

Comment: if hash code was unique, that'd be one hell of a compression algorithm.

Comment: e.g. try "Z@S.ME" and "Z@RN.E" they have the same hash values when using hashCode ;)

Comment: @Simon, just ran your example in .NET because I was curious.  They must have different base hashing algorithms because they aren't exact matches there.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/6YJRpV

Comment: Maybe what OP meant by unique is: unique-for-a-given-input-string (no two hashes should be generated for the same string).

Comment: @Simon Oh wow they collides

Answer (score 4):

I use this i tested it as key from my `EhCacheManager` Memory map ....

**Its cleaner i suppose**

```
   /**
     * Return Hash256 of String value
     *
     * @param text
     * @return 
     */
    public static String getHash256(String text) {
        try {
            return org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(text);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HashUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

am using maven but this is the jar
**commons-codec-1.9.jar**

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for generating has code for a given string.

```
int hash = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
    hash = hash*31 + charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Why did you start at 7?

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked

```
   public static long getUniqueLongFromString (String value){
       return  UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(value.getBytes()).getMostSignificantBits();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A few line of java code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       String str="test string";
       MessageDigest messageDigest=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       messageDigest.update(str.getBytes(),0,str.length());
       System.out.println("MD5: "+new BigInteger(1,messageDigest.digest()).toString(16));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the stock hashCode() method:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + charAt(i);
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

The block of code above comes from the java.lang.String class. As you can see it is a 32 bit hash code which fair enough if you are using it on a small scale of data. If you are looking for hash code with more than 32 bit, you might wanna checkout this link: 
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/strong_hash_code_implementation.shtml