# Fast Incremental Hash in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I'm looking for a hash function to hash Strings. For my purposes (identifying changed objects during an import) it should have the following properties:

1. fast
2. can be used incremental, i.e. I can use it like this:

   ```
   Hasher h = new Hasher();
   h.add("somestring");
   h.add("another part");
   h.add("eveno more");
   Long hash = h.create();
   ```

   without compromising the other properties or keeping the strings in memory during the complete process.
3. Secure against collisions. If I compare two hash values from different strings 1 million times per day for the rest of my life, the risk that I get a collision should be neglectable.

It does not have to be secure against malicious attempts to create collisions.

What algorithm can I use? An algorithm with an existent free implementation in Java is preferred.

**Clarification**

1. The hash doesn't have to be a long. A String for example would be just fine.
2. The data to be hashed will come from a file or a db, with many 10MB or up to a few GB of data, that will get distributed into different Hashes. So keeping the complete Strings in memory is not really an option.

Comment: See [what-is-a-good-64bit-hash-function-in-java-for-textual-strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660501/what-is-a-good-64bit-hash-function-in-java-for-textual-strings).

Comment: "Secure against collisions" - then hashing is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Durandal Mind explaining Why?

Comment: I guess @Durandal wanted to point out, that every hash-function has collisions. I guess what you want is a function where collisions are unlikely to happen for similar inputs.

Comment: Let's say you have another 10000 days. That's 10^10 pairs of hash values required to have a negligible probability of being equal - say, less than one ppm - easy with an image large compared to 10^16 like 63 bits or even 64. But adding a million hash codes a day and requiring each to be unique would limit your life expectancy to less than twelve years.

Comment: Whats there to explain? Hashing to decrease the amount of information to a smaller set of values will naturally always produce collisions; which is in straight conflict with the explicit requirement quoted. As for the unrelated (not quoted) relaxation of the requirement... it depends on what "neglectable" means; without a solid analysis (of inputs and method) its impossible to determine even the order of magnitude of the collision probability.

Comment: @Durandal the question is: how likely is a collision. Git is using this approach, the chances that any of us will see an accidental collision seem to be extraordinary slim.

Comment: @JensSchauder That really depends on use-case and method, just "assuming" an N-bit hash givens me a 1 in 2^N collision chance is overoptimistic in many regards. Play with the code I posted, it should provide some insight/points to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Hashs are a sensible topic and it is hard to recommend any such hash based upon your question. You might want to ask this question on https://security.stackexchange.com/ to get expert opinions on the usability of hashs in certain usecases.

What I understood so far is that most hashs are implemented incrementally in the very core; the execution-timing on the other hand is not that easy to predict.

I present you two `Hasher` implementations which rely on "an existent free implementation in Java". Both implementations are constructed in a way that you can arbitrarily split your `String`s before calling `add()` and get the same result as long as you do not change the order of the characters in them:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created for https://stackoverflow.com/q/26928529/1266906.
 */
public class Hashs {

    public static class JavaHasher {
        private int hashCode;

        public JavaHasher() {
            hashCode = 0;
        }

        public void add(String value) {
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + value.hashCode();
        }

        public int create() {
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public static class ShaHasher {
        public static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        private final MessageDigest messageDigest;

        public ShaHasher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        }

        public void add(String value) {
            messageDigest.update(value.getBytes(UTF_8));
        }

        public byte[] create() {
            return messageDigest.digest();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javaHash();

        try {
            shaHash();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        }
    }

    private static void javaHash() {
        JavaHasher h = new JavaHasher();
        h.add("somestring");
        h.add("another part");
        h.add("eveno more");
        int hash = h.create();
        System.out.println(hash);
    }

    private static void shaHash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        ShaHasher h = new ShaHasher();
        h.add("somestring");
        h.add("another part");
        h.add("eveno more");
        byte[] hash = h.create();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hash));
        System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, hash));
    }
}
```

Here obviously "SHA-256" could be replaced with other common hash-algorithms; Java ships quite a few of them.

Now you called out for a `Long` as return-value which would imply you are looking for a 64bit-Hash. If this really was on purpose have a look at the answers to [What is a good 64bit hash function in Java for textual strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660501/what-is-a-good-64bit-hash-function-in-java-for-textual-strings?lq=1). The accepted answer is a slight variant of the `JavaHasher` as `String.hashCode()` does basically the same calculation, but with lower overflow-boundary:

```
    public static class Java64Hasher {
        private long hashCode;

        public Java64Hasher() {
            hashCode = 1125899906842597L;
        }

        public void add(CharSequence value) {
            final int len = value.length();

            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                hashCode = 31*hashCode + value.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        public long create() {
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

Unto your points:

1. fast

   With SHA-256 being slower than the other two I still would call all three presented approaches fast.
2. can be used incremental without compromising the other properties or keeping the strings in memory during the complete process.

   I can not guarantee that property for the `ShaHasher` as I understand it is block-based and I lack the source code.Still I would suggest that at most one block, the hash and some internal states are kept. The other two obviously only store the partial hash between calls to `add()`
3. Secure against collisions. If I compare two hash values from different strings 1 million times per day for the rest of my life, the risk that I get a collision should be neglectable.

   For every hash there are collisions. Given a good distribution the bit-size of the hash is the main factor on how often a collision happens. The `JavaHasher` is used in e.g. `HashMap`s and seems to be "collision-free" enough to distribute similar keys far apart each other. As for any deeper analysis: do your own tests or ask your local security engineer - sorry.

I hope this gives a good starting point, details are probably mainly opinion-based.

Comment: [Looking at the open JDK sources]( http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/provider/SHA2.java?av=h#SHA2.SHA256) SHA-256 is really implemented to hold at most one block-size of data at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Not intended as an answer, just to demonstrate that hash collisions are much more likely than human intuition tends to assume.

The following tiny program generates 2^31 *distinct* strings and checks if any of their hashes collide. It does this by keeping a tracking bit per possible hash value (so you need >512MB heap to run it), to mark each hash value as "used" as they are encountered. It takes several minutes to complete.

```
public class TestStringHashCollisions {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        long collisions = 0;
        long testcount = 0;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(64);
        for (int i=0; i>=0; ++i) {
            // construct distinct string
            b.setLength(0);
            b.append("www.");
            b.append(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            b.append(".com");

            // check for hash collision
            String s = b.toString();
            ++testcount;
            if (isColliding(s.hashCode()))
                ++collisions;

            // progress printing
            if ((i & 0xFFFFFF) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Tested: " + testcount + ", Collisions: " + collisions);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Tested: " + testcount + ", Collisions: " + collisions);
        System.out.println("Collision ratio: " + (collisions / (double) testcount));
    }

    // storage for 2^32 bits in 2^27 ints
    static int[] bitSet = new int[1 << 27];

    // test if hash code has appeared before, mark hash as "used"
    static boolean isColliding(int hash) {
        int index = hash >>> 5;
        int bitMask = 1 << (hash & 31);
        if ((bitSet[index] & bitMask) != 0)
            return true;
        bitSet[index] |= bitMask;
        return false;
    }

}
```

You can adjust the string generation part easily to test different patterns.