# Best way to derive / compute a unique hash from a given String in Java

Tags: java, hash, md5, sha1, md5sum

I am looking for ways to compute a unique hash for a given String in Java. Looks like I cannot use MD5 or SHA1 because folks claim that they are broken and do not always guarantee uniqueness.

I should get the same hash (preferably a 32 character string like the MD5 Sum) for two String objects which are equal by the `equals()` method. And no other String should generate this hash - that's the tricky part.

Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: You'll *always* have collisions between some values. There are more `String`s than there are 32 character `String`s.

Comment: That's right! It's theoretically not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If guaranteed unique hash code is required then it is not possible (possible theoretically but not practically). Hashes and hash codes are non-unique.

> A Java String of length N has 65536 ^ N possible states, and requires
>   an integer with 16 * N bits to represent all possible values. If you
>   write a hash function that produces integer with a smaller range (e.g.
>   less than 16 * N bits), you will eventually find cases where more than
>   one String hashes to the same integer; i.e. the hash codes cannot be
>   unique. This is called the Pigeonhole Principle, and there is a
>   straight forward mathematical proof. (You can't fight math and win!)
>
> But if "probably unique" with a very small chance of non-uniqueness is
>   acceptable, then crypto hashes are a good answer. The math will tell
>   you how big (i.e. how many bits) the hash has to be to achieve a given
>   (low enough) probability of non-uniqueness.

Updated : check this another good answer : [What is a good 64bit hash function in Java for textual strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660501/what-is-a-good-64bit-hash-function-in-java-for-textual-strings)