# HashSet contains method, strange behavior

Tags: java

here is my code :

```
public class testGui {



    public static void main(String[] arg){
        class TESTS{
            String t;

            public TESTS(String t){
                this.t = t;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object x){
                System.out.println("My method is called...");
                if(x instanceof TESTS){
                    TESTS zzz = (TESTS) x;
                    return zzz.t.compareTo(t)==0;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
        HashSet<TESTS> allItems = new HashSet<TESTS>();
        allItems.add(new TESTS("a"));
        allItems.add(new TESTS("a"));
        System.out.println(allItems.contains(new TESTS("a")));
    }

}
```

I do not get why the hashset contains method is not calling my equals method as mentionned in their specifications :

> More formally, adds the specified
>   element, o, to this set if this set
>   contains no element e such that
>   (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

My code is returning false and not going into my equals method.

Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you override [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), you must also override [`hashCode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).  Otherwise, equal objects will have different hash codes and be considered unequal.

It is also strongly recommended not to override *only* `hashCode`.  But this is not essential, as unequal objects can have the same hash code.

Comment: They won't be considered unequal. It's just that the HashSet won't even invoke the equals method because it only does it for hashCodes leading to the same bucket. And overriding only hashCode doesn't have any sense, since HashSet will always call equals for objects having the same hashCodes.

Comment: @JB, yes, the fact that they lead to different buckets means they are considered 'unequal' (considered different objects).  I am not referring to the `equals` method when I use that term.  I also agree overriding only `hashCode` is illogical, which is why I strongly recommended against it.  However, it doesn't break the contract.

Comment: It would be nice if the java documentation mentioned that hashcode is called first. I just got burned by this issue in java 5.

Comment: @Aaron, not only would it be nice, I would argue that at the moment, it's downright incorrectly documented, and this has persisted through to current-day Java. It says that the contains and add methods are equivalent to Objects.equals, but they demonstrably are not.

Answer (score 7):

The HashSet depends on the HashCode of each object. Before the equals method is called, the hashCode method will be called. If hashcodes are equal, then the hashset deems it worthy of evaluating the equals method.

Implement a hashcode method such that if a.equals(b) == true, then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()

and it should start working as you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

You should also implement `hashCode`, so that it is consistent with `equals`. `HashSet` uses the `hashCode` method to decide which bucket to put an item into, and calls `equals` only when the hash code of two items are the same.

*Effective Java, 2nd Edition* discusses this rule (and the consequences of breaking it) in **Item 9: Always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that was really helpful, I found the answer before you answered (didn't know how to cancell the question), but what you wrote is what I done and it solved my problem ;).

Answer (score 0):

As most of the comments have been... just override the hashcode method (sample below) and you should be good.

```
@Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return t.hashCode()*31;
        }
```

Comment: What do you gain by multiplying by 31?

Comment: this thread will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier