# correct implementation of hashcode()

Tags: java

I have a pojo , in which I have defined the hashcode method myself that is..

```
 public int hashCode()
     {       
     return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;       

 }
```

But since I am using eclipse IDE , it also provide my automatically generated hashcode which is..

```
     @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((job == null) ? 0 : job.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + salary;
    return result;
}
```

Now my query is that what's the differnce between the two, which one implemenatation is better..! My complete pojo is...

```
enter codepackage CollectionsPrac;
```

public class Employee {

```
 String name,job;
 int salary;


 public Employee(String n , String j, int t )
 {
     this.name= n;
     this.job=j;
     this.salary= t;         
 }


 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((job == null) ? 0 : job.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + salary;
    return result;
}


 /*@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (job == null) {
        if (other.job != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!job.equals(other.job))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (salary != other.salary)
        return false;
    return true;
}
 */

/* @Override
 public int hashCode()
     {       
     return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;       

 }*/

 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
     if (this == obj)  
    {  
        return true;   
    }  
    // make sure o can be cast to this class  
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass())  
    {  
        // cannot cast  
        return false;  
    }           

     Employee e = (Employee) obj;   
     return this.name.equals(e.name)&&this.job.equals(e.job)&&this.salary==e.salary;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
        return name+"\t" +"\t"+  job +"\t"+ salary;
    }
```

}
 here

Answer (score 4):

The Eclipse-generate `hashCode()` is much more sensitive when it comes to small changes in your POJO. E.g. if you switch `job` and `name` values with each other, your `hashCode()` will return the same value (addition is commutative) while the fancy Eclipse version will return something completely different:

```
System.out.println(new Employee("John", "Blacksmith", 100).hashCode());
System.out.println(new Employee("Blacksmith", "John", 100).hashCode());

//your version of hashCode() produces identical result:
376076563
376076563

//Eclipse version:
-1520263300
926019626
```

## See also

- [Why does Java's hashCode() in String use 31 as a multiplier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304)

Comment: Hi , so please can you tell me whats wrong with my implemnentation of hashcode()..!1

Comment: Your version generates many more (bad) hash collisions than Eclipse's version.

Comment: @user1334074: see my update. Basically it is desired that `hashCode()` should return different results for slightly different objects.

Comment: Hi Tomasz ,Thanks a lot , so practically which hashcode() implementaion I should go, eclipse one..!!

Comment: Hi Louis , thanks a lot...for explaining that my hashcode generates generates many more (bad) hash collisions than Eclipse's version,,could you please explain this alo in simpler terms , that will make understandings more clear..!thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference is that your implementation will throw a `NullPointerException` if `job` or `name` is `null`.

Additionally, the method eclipse generates results in a more irregular hashcode, which in theory means there is a lower likelihood of hashtables degenerating and having poor performance, but in practice that probably won't matter since `java.util.HashMap` uses an auxiallary hash function to scramble the hashcode before using it.

Comment: Hi Michael, could you please provide the correct implementation of hash code() for this class that will be a great help..!! Thanks in advance..!

Comment: @user1334074: Why don't you just use the one generated by eclipse?

Comment: Hi Miachel ,I am using that one rite Now, if you could please provide me with the hashcode() just I hve generated that will be a great help..!!