# Java Fastest Hash Function

Tags: java, hash, hash-function

I have a Boolean string (like "01100..001") of length 128 characters (means 128 number of 0/1). I am searching for an efficient (fast) hash function in Java, which produce a much lower representation than 128 bit and obviously with less collision. Can anybody help me, is there any such hash function ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Less collision than the zero you'd get with a 128-bit representation?

Comment: @eggyal, Thanks a lot. Nice concept. It will help me lot. :)

Comment: Using a String for just storing a 128-bit value seems to me a bit of overkill, a waste of memory and - especially if you care on performance - definitely not the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `.hashCode()` method on Java `String` class, it returns an `int` and it is very fast.

Or you can use the `.hashCode()` method on `java.util.BitSet` as Pulsar suggest, if you prefer store your data in `BitSet`.

Comment: I was going to say that except that I would've converted the `String` to `BigInteger` first and called the `.hashCode()` method for that. But I'm guessing it's faster to just hash the original `String` like you suggested. Just wondering why you'd want to have 16 bytes stored as a 128 byte `String`, that seems like a huge waste of space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will be nice one to try. However, is there any document stating the probability of collision ?

Comment: @ZeroOne, I am also thinking to convert it to BigInt and then call hashcode. Because, I think that will create less collisions.

Comment: Try to read this answer about collisions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier

Comment: Using the `hashCode()` of `BitSet` as per @Pulsar's answer is probably better.

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using a `java.util.BitSet` instead, depending on what you are doing it could be a lot easier and more efficient? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html
It has a `.hashCode()` method as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will be nice one to try. However, is there any document stating that probability of collision ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I know it was improved back in 2004 (see bug parade: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4979028) and the java doc show (defines?) how the hashcode is calculated: The source is available as well of course. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate the hash of a string, simply use the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) method of the `String` class. Depending on the implementation, several optimizations are made for quickly computing this value.

As an example, in [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java)'s implementation of the `String` class the `hashCode()` method caches the value in the `hash` attribute and only needs to be computed once.

And who said that a string of 128 characters has a hash of 128-bits? all hashes returned by the `hashCode()` method in Java are of type `int`, and ints in Java are represented using 32-bits.