# function computing a hash number, what exactly does it do and why?

Tags: c, hash

I know this function is doing something with hash numbers,
but didnt understand exactly the purpose of this function?
why "res *31 + *key"?
why 31?

```
unsigned int HashAlg(char* key)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;

    while (*key != 0)
    {
        res = res * 31 + *key;
        ++key;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Java's hashCode() in String use 31 as a multiplier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier)

Answer (score 5):

The implementation is a variation of a multiplicative string hash function by D.J. Bernstein:

```
unsigned djb_hash ( void *key, int len )
{
  unsigned char *p = key;
  unsigned h = 0;
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    h = 33 * h + p[i];

  return h;
}
```

The purpose of hash functions like these is to map a search key, like the string `"item1"`, to an index which can then be used in a hash table, a cache, etc.; simplistically, the hash value gives us the place in the table where the corresponding record for `"item1"` should be stored. Hash tables, in turn, are used to implement associative arrays and dynamic sets. For more detail I recommend starting at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_tables).

You can see that in your implementation, the constant `33` has been switched for `31`. There isn't much real mathematical work which can definitively prove the relationship between prime numbers and hashing functions. The basic concept of using prime numbers in hash functions revolve around the concept of transforming the current state of the hash function (applying some form of mathematical operation such as multiplication or addition to the hash value). The result is constrained to be a new hash value that should statistically have a higher entropic value or in other words a very low bit-bias for any of the bits in the new hash value. In simple terms, when you multiply a set of random numbers by a prime number, the resulting numbers (when analyzed at a bit level) should show no bias towards being one state or another, i.e. `P(Bi = 1) ~= 0.5`. There is no concrete proof that this is the case or that it only happens with prime numbers, it just seems to be an ongoing self-proclaimed intuition that we seem obliged to follow. These properties are judged a-posteriori, meaning we try to analyze hash function (or PRNG) properties with chosen constants and develop an intuition which constants "work well", i.e. producing specific distributions or demonstrating an avalanche effect, produce a uniform distribution for a specific set of inputs, etc.

Comment: Well, you want the hash function to generate all values with as uniform distribution as possible, so you want to use a constant such that (_n_ * _k_) % _table_size_ can yield all values 0 to _table_size_. That is the case when _k_ is not co-divisible with _table_size_. And primes are not co-divisible with anything but themselves, so they make the safest choice.

Comment: Not the safest a priori, but certainly the first to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> why "res *31 + *key"

Suppose what happens if it were only `res = res + *key`; then the hash would just add up all values in the key. That would yield the same hash for permuted strings like hello, elloh, olleh, loleh, etc. Multiplying with a value > 1 makes this much less likely.

> why 31?

Probably to avoid a power of 2 which would simply shift left a value and lose it after a few shifts. A non-power of 2 avoids this problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the "why 31" in more details please?

Comment: Well, there are mathematical reasons to chose a prime and avoid powers of two, in order to get close to an even distribution of hashes over the input range and avoid hash collisions.

Comment: OK, how prime number help here?