# difference between creating java string with and without new operator

Tags: java

With new operator String create the string in heap and put a copy in string const pool so the result of hashcode is same in below case;

```
  String s1 = new String("Test");
   String s2 = new String("Test");
   System.out.println(s1.hashCode() + " "+ s2.hashCode() + " " + s1.equals(s2));
```

But without using new operator its still giving the same hashcode

```
String s1 = new String("Test");
    String s2 = "Test";
    System.out.println(s1.hashCode() + " "+ s2.hashCode() + " " + s1.equals(s2));
```

Then what is the differnce between above two notation of string creation although  they are referening to same string in string const. pool

Comment: Hu ? hashcode of strings is based on the characters of the string.

Comment: Try (s1 == s2) - if it's true they are the same instance

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Effective java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf).

> It is often appropriate to reuse a single object instead of creating a
>   new function- ally equivalent object each time it is needed. Reuse can
>   be both faster and more stylish. An object can always be reused if it
>   is immutable. As an extreme example of what not to do,
>   consider this statement:
>
> **String s = new String("stringette"); // DON'T
>   DO THIS!**
>
> The statement creates a new String instance each time it is
>   executed, and none of those object creations is necessary. The
>   argument to the String construc- tor ( "stringette" ) is itself a
>   String instance, functionally identical to all of the objects created
>   by the constructor. If this usage occurs in a loop or in a frequently
>   invoked method, millions of String instances can be created
>   needlessly.
>
> The improved version is simply the following:
>
> **String s = "stringette";**
>
> This version uses a single String instance, rather than creating a new
>   one each time it is executed. Furthermore, it is guaranteed that the
>   object will be reused by any other code running in the same virtual
>   machine that happens to con- tain the same string literal

therefore creating unnecessary new Object of String or any other Objects are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

From docs and `Java.lang.String` class, Internal Implementation of `hashCode()`

> /**
>        * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
>        * `String` object is computed as
>        *
>
> > ```
> >      * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s1*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> >      *
> > ```
>
> * using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the
>        * *i*th character of the string, `n` is the length of
>        * the string, and `^` indicates exponentiation.
>        * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
>        *
>        * @return  a hash code value for this object.
>        */

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
    int len = count;
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

More about String hashcode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518418/whats-behind-the-hashcode-method-for-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Both expression gives you String object, but there is difference between them. When you create String object using new() operator, it always create `a new object in heap memory`. On the other hand, if you create object using String literal syntax e.g. `String s2 = "Test";` `it may return an existing object from String pool` (a cache of String object in Perm gen space, which is now moved to heap space in recent Java release), if it's already exists. Otherwise it will create a new string object and put in string pool for future re-use.

for further reading see:[here](http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/08/difference-between-string-literal-and-new-String-object-Java.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
 String str = new String("String");
```

always create a new object on the heap.

Here creates a new String having for value the value of the constant "String" and assignates its reference to the variable str.

```
String str = "String";
```

uses the [String pool](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html)

Here assignates the reference associated to the constant "String" to the variable str