# What is the use of the 'new' operator for String in Java?

Tags: java, return, return-value

I have a really basic question about using `new` in java statement. For example, the return clause at the very end uses `new` for `String`. Why `String` here needs to be created? Under what kind of situations would people choose to use `new`?

```
public class A extends java.lang.Object {

    public int number;

    public String toString() {

        return new String("Value : " + number);

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519657/difference-between-creating-java-string-with-and-without-new-operator and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952581/what-is-the-difference-between-strings-allocated-using-new-operator-without-ne

Answer (score 7):

Under no circumstance, since `String` is immutable there is no purpose in explicitly creating a copy of a string unless you really need a copy, from Javadoc, about the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)):

> **Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.**

An expression `"Value : " + number` already evaluates as a new `String` so `return new String("Value : " + number)` is equivalent to

```
String tmp = "Value : " + number;
return new String(tmp);
```

Which you can see creates an useless copy.

Answer (score 1):

`new String("Value:" + number)` is redundant. 

You attempt to instantiate a new **String** object by copying an existing string.Constructing new **String** object in this way is rarely necessary, and may cause performance problems if done often enough.
This is enough:

```
public class A extends java.lang.Object {

    public int number;

    public String toString() {
        return "Value : " + number;
    }

}
```