# How do I correct my hash function?

Tags: java, hash, numbers, double

This question is a result of the responses submitted to [my post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46152/a-library-class-point) at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

---

I have a `class` called `Point`, which is basically "intended to encapsulate a *point* represented in 2D space." I have overrided the `hashcode()` function which is as follows:

```
...
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getX())
            ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getX()) >>> 32));
    hash += (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getY())
            ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getY()) >>> 32));
    return hash;
}
...
```

Let me clarify (for those who didn't check the above link) that my `Point` uses the two `double`s: `x` and `y` to represent its coordinates.

**Problem:**
My Problem is evident when I run this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p1 = Point.getCartesianPoint(12, 0);
    Point p2 = Point.getCartesianPoint(0, 12);
    System.out.println(p1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(p2.hashCode());
}
```

I get the *Output:*

```
1076363264
1076363264
```

This is clearly a problem. Basically I intend my `hashcode()` to return **equal hashcodes for equal Points**. If I reverse the order in one of the parameter declarations (i.e. swap `12` with `1` in one of them to get equal `Point`s), I get the correct (same) result. How can I correct my approach while maintaining the *quality* or *uniqueness* of the hash?

Comment: Right-click in the your IDE, choose "Generate equals and hashCode", and examine the correct implementation produced by your IDE. Or use `Objects.hash(x, y)`.

Comment: Generally - to produce a meaningful `hashCode()` you have to shift it every time you introduce another property into calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the code that is present in [Arrays.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) already?

```
  Arrays.hashCode(new double[]{x,y});
```

This is what guava for example is using in [Objects.hashCode.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29)

If you have Java 7, simply:

```
 Objects.hash(x,y)
```

Comment: That would lead to the exact same problem of symmetry. He's better use `Arrays.hashCode(new double[] {x, y})`, or simply `Objects.hash(x, y)`.

Comment: Please note... I'm accepting this because it's the shortest (and easiest) answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get an integer hash code for two doubles that is unique, without some further information about the numbers being made available about the nature of the numbers in the doubles.

**Why?**

int is stored as a 32bit representation, double as a 64 bit representation ([see the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

So you are trying to store 128 bits of information in a 32 bit space, so it can never give an unique hash.

**However**

1. This really isn't [the purpose of a hash code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), hash codes
   just need to have fairly uncommon collisions to be useful.
2. If you
   know something about the double numbers, that reduces their
   entropy/information content then you could use this to compress the
   number of bits they use. This will be dependant on the application
   of this class that you have not discussed yet.
3. This is why equals
   normally does not make use of the hashcode to check for equality,
   use getX and getY of each Point to do the comparison instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public int hashCode() {
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
    int hash = 31 + (int) (bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
    bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
    hash = 31 * hash + (int) (bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
    return hash;
}
```

this implementation follows `Arrays.hashCode(double a[])` pattern.
It produces these hash codes:

```
-992476223
1076364225
```

You can find suggestions how to write good hashCode in Effective Java Item. 9

Comment: Please explain in more detail why you use `31`? It's just because  31 is a prime number? Could I use`23` instead?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. It seems that `NetBeans` uses that stratergy as well: `int hash = 5;
        hash = 41 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.x) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.x) >>> 32));
        hash = 41 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.y) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.y) >>> 32));
        return hash;`

Comment: @ADS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier

Comment: See Effective Java Item. 9: The value 31 was chosen because it is
an odd prime...

Comment: Be warned, that whilst this distinguishes between these two points uniquely, it is not guaranteed for all points. (see my post above). It really does depend on what your objectives are for calculating the Hash.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a silly idea, bt you are using + which is a symetric operation and you are getting symetric problems. What if you ue a non-symmetric operation such as division (check for denominator == 0 though) or minus? Or any other that you cna find in literature or invent yourself.