# contains in HashSet<int[]>()

Tags: android, contains, hashset

In android I'm trying to save grids that the user already have pressed.

Code snipping I’m using is:

```
// private
private HashSet<int[]> PlayerSelectedHashField = new HashSet<int[]>();
private boolean collisionDetected = false;
```

In a function I’m using

```
collisionDetected = PlayerSelectedHashField.contains(TmpPos); // -> Fail - not working
{doing something}
PlayerSelectedHashField.add(TmpPos); // int[] TmpPos - TmpPos is x y
```

The .add function is working as expected, but .contains always return false.
Why does it not working - and what can I do instead?

Comment: because the hash of an int[] is related to the object instance, not to its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
}
```

containsKey:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}
```

getNode:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It will not work since `equals` of `arrays` will do a `==` compare, and it will return true only if they point to the same instance.

Your problem could be fixed without work with `Arrays.equals` (the way to compare two arrays elements and not reference) (could be problematic (at least, for me.) i prefer an easy way)

Since you save `X` and `Y` coordinates, just make a class `Point`

```
public class Point {
    public final int X;
    public final int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj instanceof Point) {
            Point pObj = (Point) obj;
            return pObj.X == X && pObj.Y == Y;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = X;
        result = 31 * result + Y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

then use `Point` class to save `X, Y` points.

Instead of create your custom point class, you can use the Android [`Point`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html).

Example

```
Set<Point> points = new HashSet<Point>();
points.add(new Point(1, 3));
points.add(new Point(1, 4));

System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(1, 3)));
System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(1, 4)));
System.out.println(points.contains(new Point(1, 5)));
```

Comment: Good answer, FYI there already is a [Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) class that OP could use.

Comment: Oh i didn't read Android tag. I will add it thanks @ashishduh

Comment: quick question: why 31?

Comment: @njzk2 Because 31 is an odd prime. Effective Java 2nd edition have a great description about it. Here mattb quoted him http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier

Comment: Fabulous example. It worked fine with <points> but not with int[]. Actually I hade already tried with points but had forget “new Point” inside contains. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the `HashSet` javadocs:

> public boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So, generally, if you don't know what happens when you call `equals` on a particular object type, then `contains` also may not behave as you expect. It is never a bad idea to make a class for a particular object if that object type has conceptual meaning in your program. If you do that, you can override the `equals` method to make sure it is behaving exactly as you want.