# Suggestion regarding Good Hash Function

Tags: c++, hash

I want to create a hash table in c++ for storing  strings. I am willing to write a good hash function to avoid collisions as much as possible. As a sample hash function I have used the following method:

function Hash(string)

return (summation of the ASCII values of the characters in the string) mod     PrimeNumber

end

Is this function good enough to avoid collisions or is there any other good function ? please help :)

N.B: No STL is allowed

Comment: Did you search for existing hash functions? Do they not do what you need?

Comment: I am just searching for a function which will avoid collision as much as possible. Do u have any idea? @Neil

Comment: How do you perform `mod` operation on a string?

Comment: using summation of the ASCII values of the characters. @interjay

Comment: Just use `std::hash` wherever possible. If you have multiple values to hash, use `boost::hash_combine` or `boost::hash_range`.

Comment: All anagrams will hash to the same value, that doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: I am sure the built-in hash code function for C++ strings is more than adequate for most uses. If you are curious about how to compute hash codes for strings, check out [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier) about java's string hash code.

Comment: Any reason not to use `std::unordered_map`? Or the Boost or TR1 `unordered_map`, or even the old STL `hash_map`, if you can't use C++11 for some reason?

Comment: yap. I have to apply it manually @Mike

Answer (score 2):

c++11 already comes with a good hash function for string you don't need to introduce one. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/