# How to use a primitive list or List as a key of a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to use an int array as key in C# and the behaviour I'm seeing is unexpected (for me).

```
var result = new Dictionary<int[], int>();
result[new [] {1, 1}] = 100;
result[new [] {1, 1}] = 200;

Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count); // false is 2
```

It seems the same with List too.

```
var result = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>();
result[new List<int> { 1, 1 }] = 100;
result[new List<int> { 1, 1 }] = 200;

Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count); // false is 2
```

I'm expecting the Dictionary to use Equals to decide if a Key is present in the map. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Can someone explain why and how I can get this sort of behaviour to work?

Comment: Default equality is instance equality of the array/list itself, not the contents of the data structure. You're passing two different instances with the same contents, which doesn't cause a key collision. You can pass your own `IEqualityComperer` when constructing the dictionary that can use whatever logic you'd like to compare keys for equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET lists and arrays do not have a built-in equality comparison, so you need to provide your own:

```
class ArrayEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]> {

    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<int[]> Instance =
        new ArrayEqComparer();

    public bool Equals(int[] b1, int[] b2) {
        if (b2 == null && b1 == null)
           return true;
        else if (b1 == null | b2 == null)
           return false;
        return b1.SequenceEqual(b2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] a) {
        return a.Aggregate(37, (p, v) => 31*v + p);
    }
}
```

Now you can construct your dictionary as follows:

```
var result = new Dictionary<int[],int>(ArrayEqComparer.Instance);
```

Comment: Is there a built-in Dictionary with this behaviour already? Or in a popular library?

Comment: @joejag Much to my surprise, there isn't a built-in equality comparator for collections, even though the framework has enough "plumbing" to make it work generically. I don't know of any popular library to provide this functionality, either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why 37 and 31 in your `GetHasCode`?

Comment: @devuxer I started multiplying by 31 after looking at Java's implementation of `hashCode` in `String`. [Here is a good explanation of why it was done](http://stackoverflow.com/q/299304/335858). I picked 37 as another small prime more or less at random.

Comment: This shows the equality issue:
Assert.IsTrue(new[] {1, 1} == new[] { 1, 1 }); // false

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary class allows a custom equality comparer as a dictionary comparer.  Implement IEqualityComparer> by providing a GetHashCode(IList obj) by returning the xor (the ^ operator) of all list elements (0 ^ first ^ second...) and Equals(IList x, IList y) by using Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEquals.  Then pass an instance of that to the Dictionary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing **new** object (array or list) as a key. As a **new** object it has a different reference so it is accepted as new key.