# Why Java implement different hashcode method of Set and ArrayList?

Tags: java, hashcode

```
 // this is the hashCode method of Set
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode();
    }
    return h;
}



//this is the hashCode method of List
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

why java use these two different approaches? Is there anything related to the characteristic of Set and List? 
Why it uses 31 but not other numbers?
Thanks!

Comment: I answered the part about List vs Set, because I couldn't find any other questions on SO about that. But the bit about 31 is already answered: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304, as well as other answers if you search for why hash functions use prime numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sets are unordered, so `{a, b, c}` must have the same hash code as `{c, b, a}`. Addition is commutative, so adding the elements' hashCodes gives you that property.

Lists are ordered, so while `[a, b, c]` *may* have the same hash code as `[c, b, a]`, it does not need to -- and it'd be better if it didn't, since as much as possible non-equal objects should try to have non-equal hashCodes. The ArrayList.hashCode implementation has that property.

Note that Set and List both define how implementations must define `equals` and `hashCode` ([`Set.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#hashCode--), [`List.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--)), so any (compliant) implementation of those respective collections is going to look pretty much the same. This gives you the useful property that a Set containing the same elements is equal (and thus has the same hashCode) as any other Set, regardless of the underlying implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to elaborate a bit more analytical, on this interesting topic.

As defined from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), there must be a contract between equals and hashCode.

The **general contract of hashCode is**:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
> execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
> return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
> comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
> consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
> of the same application.
>
> If two objects are equal according to the
> equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
> two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> **It is not required**
> that if two objects are unequal according to the
> equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
> each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
> **However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
> integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
> hash tables.**

So let's see what the contract for `equals` is for `List`.

As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) by Oracle for `equals` method:

> In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the
> same elements in the same order.

So if we check now how the `hashCode` is implemented for `List`

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

The line `hashCode = 31*hashCode ...` ensures that the order of the list elements for which the `hashcode` method calculates the total result, affects the final result.

If this was not there and it was defined simple as `hashCode = hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());` **then 2 lists with the same elements in different order might be `unequal` according to `equals` but produce the same hashcode.** This is **not necessary** according to contract, but it could improve the performance so that is why Oracle applied it.

For `Set` implementation of `hashcode` this is not required since the ordering is not related at all with `equals` of Set. 2 Sets can be unequal and this is not related at all with the ordering of elements since Set by default does not have a specific order.

So the implemented `hashcode` for `Set` does not need any shuffling with `.. 31*hashcode...` and so it can be as is.

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode();
    }
```