# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistence

After upgraded Spring to v.6 and Spring boot to v.3 (and automatically Hibernate to 6.1.5), tests started to fail because of `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading`

I have an entity class AClass with a field

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aClass", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<BClass> items;
```

When repository of AClass is triggering several methods, hashCode method is invoked and when it tries to execute `items.hashCode()`, I'm getting the exception:

```
2022-12-13T09:42:46.314+01:00 ERROR 15336 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure           : HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:807)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:995)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:981)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:170)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at app//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionLoaderSingleKey.load(CollectionLoaderSingleKey.java:121)
    at app//org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:789)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at app//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1710)
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:613)
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:611)
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
    at app//org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:407)
    at app//xyz.example.AClass.hashCode(AClass.java:52)
...
```

When I used default Lombok hashCode method, or IntelliJ default like

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = super.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (x != null ? x.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (y != null ? y.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (z != null ? z.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (items != null ? items.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting exception, but when I removed this line:

```
    result = 31 * result + (items != null ? items.hashCode() : 0);
```

tests are passing. However, I wouldn't like to remove `items` from hashCode method.

Comment: `items.hashCode()` iterates over the elements in the list and calls `.hashCode()` on each element.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111868/why-java-implement-different-hashcode-method-of-set-and-arraylist

Comment: A cause for this behaviour could be the change of the circular dependency detection, see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#fetch-circularity-determination

Comment: Looks like a Bug in Hibernate, see https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/force-initializing-collection-loading/7172