# NewsApp crashes when clicking on past Articles

Tags: android, kotlin

My app crashes when I attempt to click on articles published days ago, however it works fine when I tried to do it on a more recent article, here is an image for reference.

[image]

The app crashes when I scroll down and click on past news, the app also seems to be quite laggy and unresponsive, would appreciate any advice.

The error seems to lie on the `Onclicklistener` portion of the code, I uploaded all the codes which I think are relevant.

**Runtime error**

From the errors below, the classes highlighted were the `BreakingNews` and the `NewsAdapter`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.ROOM.Source.hashCode(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.ROOM.Article.hashCode(Unknown Source:71)
    at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.hashCode(NavBackStackEntry.kt:256)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.linkChildToParent(NavController.kt:143)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1918)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1813)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1721)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1719)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:287)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:198)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:164)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1454)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.Fragments.BreakingNews$onViewCreated$1.invoke(BreakingNews.kt:57)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.Fragments.BreakingNews$onViewCreated$1.invoke(BreakingNews.kt:53)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.Adapter.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-2$lambda-1(NewsAdapter.kt:82)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.Adapter.NewsAdapter.$r8$lambda$xRXjhIuiNyf8fdAGPo8jTchti_k(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.thenewsapplication.Adapter.NewsAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Article class**
(The article itself)
I extended the `serialization` class so I can pass info between fragments via `Bundle`

```
data class Article(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int? =null,
val author: String?,
val content: String?,
val description: String?,
val publishedAt: String?,
val source: Source?,
val title: String?,
val url: String,
val urlToImage: String?
) : Serializable
```

**Source**  (for the source datatype in the Article data class)

```
data class Source(
val id: Any,
val name: String
)
```

**TypeConverters**  (Convert the `Source` datatype to a primative type)

```
class Converters {

@TypeConverter
fun fromSource(source: Source): String{
    return source.name
}

@TypeConverter
fun toSource(name: String): Source {
    return Source(name, name)
}

}
```

**Adapter** (Adapter for the `BreakingNews` class RecyclerView)

```
class NewsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val ivArticleImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)
    val tvSource = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvSource)
    val tvTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
    val tvDescription = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDescription)
    val tvPublishedAt = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPublishedAt)




}

private val diffcallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem.url == newItem.url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
}
}




val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffcallback)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
    return ArticleViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_article_preview,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )


}

fun setOnItemClickListener(listen: (Article) -> Unit){
    Log.d("NewsAdapter", "setOnItem")
    onItemClickListener = listen
}

private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val article = differ.currentList[position]

    holder.itemView.apply {

        Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(holder.ivArticleImage)
        holder.tvSource.text = article.source?.name
        holder.tvTitle.text = article.title
        holder.tvDescription.text = article.description
        holder.tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
        setOnClickListener{
            Log.d("NewsAdapter", "onBindViewHolder")
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(article)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}

}
```

**BreakingNews**  (The Fragment/UI)

```
class BreakingNews: Fragment(R.layout.breakingnews) {
lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter
lateinit var binding: BreakingnewsBinding

val TAG = "BreakingNewsFragment"

var isLoading = false
var isLastPage = false
var isScrolling = false

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = BreakingnewsBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    val view = binding.root;
    return view;
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
    setupRecyclerView()

    newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putSerializable("article",it)  //Passing data between activity or fragments, work based on key/value pairs. Since we have denoted our Article Class to be of type Serializable, we can use this to pass data.
        }
        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_breakingNews_to_newsDetailsFragment,
            bundle
        )
    }

    viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer{response ->
        when (response){
            is Resource.Success -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.data?.let {newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles.toList())
                    val totalPages = newsResponse.totalResults / QUERY_PAGE_SIZE + 2

                    isLastPage = viewModel.breakingNewsPage == totalPages
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                showProgressBar()
                response.message?.let {
                    Log.e(TAG,"An error occured $it")
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                hideProgressBar()
            }
        }
    })


}

private fun hideProgressBar() {
    binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    isLoading = false
}

private fun showProgressBar() {
    binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    isLoading = true
}

var scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
            isScrolling = true
        }
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
        val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount

        val isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage = !isLoading && !isLastPage
        val isAtLastItem = firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount
        val isNotAtBeginning = firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
        val isTotalMoreThanVisible = totalItemCount >= QUERY_PAGE_SIZE
        val shouldPaginate =
            isNotLoadingAndNotLastPage && isAtLastItem && isNotAtBeginning && isTotalMoreThanVisible && isScrolling
        if (shouldPaginate) {
            viewModel.getBreakingNews("us")
            isScrolling = false
        }
    }
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
    binding.breakingNews.apply {
        adapter = newsAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        addOnScrollListener(this@BreakingNews.scrollListener)
    }
}
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not about being old article and new article, it's about that articles have id of `null`. To prevent that organize your data classes like below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles")
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
): Serializable {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(url.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

```
data class Source(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
): Serializable {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(name.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + name.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: That solves the problem thanks, however I am curious, what is the point of multiplying the `id.hashcode` and `name.hashcode` by 31? Why 31 and not any number? What does this actually do?

Comment: I use it in my projects when i face this type of situations. I thought that it was just a prime number, but with you asking i just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299304/4058604). We are using `id` because we want it to be not null. When it is null, then it will add `url.hashCode` to it, and we know that `url` values has something in it, because we check it, and most likely are unique.

Comment: Do you know the reason why we need to declare the `id` value as null?

Comment: Because the API you are using can have an article with `null` id. And you need `id` because you use `room` and your primary key is `id` which can not be null. So with this code i shared, you prevent it to be `null`. The API on the other hand use `url` for that distinction.