# Find duplicates in array of complex types

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a c# class `Look`:

```cs
public class Look
{
    public int HairId { get; set; }
    public int MakeupId { get; set; }
    public int[] ClothesIds { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have an array of Looks. I want to find duplicated items in this array. If I didn't have `ClothesIds` array inside the `Look`, I could use `GroupBy`:

```cs
looks.GroupBy(x => new {x.HairId, x.MakeupId})
                       .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                       .Select(g => g.Key);
```

But how I can write a similar code in my case?

Comment: Why not make `class Look` implement `IEquatable<Look>`?

Comment: ^^ While implementing that: I assume you consider the order of ids in ClothesIds irrelevant, right?

Comment: @Fildor No, the order is not mandatory.

Comment: @Dai it didn't work for me. However, I could find a way to do that using `IEqualityComparer`. I will check the solution and write it to the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the suggestions in the comments and the updated clarification that the order of IDs in the array doesn't affect equality:

### Code

```
public class Look : IEquatable<Look>
{
    public int HairId { get; set; }
    public int MakeupId { get; set; }
    public int[] ClothesIds { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Look other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return HairId == other.HairId &&
               MakeupId == other.MakeupId &&
               new HashSet<int>(ClothesIds).SetEquals(other.ClothesIds);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is null || !(obj is Look))
            return false;

        return Equals((Look)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = HairId;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ MakeupId;

            if (ClothesIds != null)
            {
                foreach (int id in ClothesIds.OrderBy(i => i))
                {
                    hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ id;
                }
            }

            return hashCode;
        }
    }    
}
```

### Usage

```
Look a1 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 1, 42 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look a2 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 1, 42 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look a3 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 42, 1 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look b = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 99 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look c = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { }, HairId = 8, MakeupId = 9 };

var looks = new Look[] { a1, a2, a3, b, c };

var dupes = looks.GroupBy(look => look)
                     .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(group => group);
```

a1, a2, and a3 are all considered duplicates of each other. They are also all equal to each other (`a1.Equals(a2) == true` etc.) and they all have the same hash code [as required when overriding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0) `Equals()` (Types that override Equals(Object) must also override GetHashCode; otherwise, hash tables might not work correctly.)

### Comment on GetHashCode() implementation

There was some discussion in the comments about hash speed vs. the importance of reducing hash collisions in the GetHashCode() implementation.

If the int array typically only has a few elements sorting is very fast but still a lot slower than using the array length for that part of the hash calculation. At the end of the day, the best choice for hash method comes down to the shape of the data and what your program does with it. A good compromise between collision rate and hash speed could be to XOR the array elements together (without sorting, since that operation produces the same number regardless of element order)

#### Calculating the Hash Code

Some options for calculating the array portion of the hash code are to simply use the array length (fast but the most collisions), combining the integers in the array with XOR then combining that result with the contributions from other properties, or treating each integer in the array the same way as other integer properties by [multiplying it by an odd prime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299748/141172) then XORing that result (slowest with fewest hash collisions).

The third option requires the array to be sorted so that the same set of integers in the array produces the same hash code. The second option does not since XOR is a [commutative operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Here's a benchmark of those options

##### Key Results

| Method | NumArrayElements | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CalcHash_Len | 1 | 0.6292 ns | 0.0031 ns | 0.0025 ns |
| CalcHash_Xor | 1 | 0.8714 ns | 0.0054 ns | 0.0048 ns |
| CalcHash_Sort | 1 | 111.8397 ns | 1.8789 ns | 1.7575 ns |
| CalcHash_Len | 10 | 0.6713 ns | 0.0119 ns | 0.0106 ns |
| CalcHash_Xor | 10 | 5.6004 ns | 0.0430 ns | 0.0381 ns |
| CalcHash_Sort | 10 | 255.7398 ns | 2.5835 ns | 2.4166 ns |
| CalcHash_Len | 100 | 0.6453 ns | 0.0262 ns | 0.0245 ns |
| CalcHash_Xor | 100 | 49.1987 ns | 0.4325 ns | 0.3834 ns |
| CalcHash_Sort | 100 | 2,914.2557 ns | 12.0316 ns | 10.6657 ns |
| CalcHash_Len | 1000 | 0.6282 ns | 0.0061 ns | 0.0051 ns |
| CalcHash_Xor | 1000 | 448.0222 ns | 1.4675 ns | 1.3009 ns |
| CalcHash_Sort | 1000 | 40,017.2176 ns | 205.8713 ns | 182.4995 ns |
| CalcHash_Len | 10000 | 0.6287 ns | 0.0059 ns | 0.0055 ns |
| CalcHash_Xor | 10000 | 4,516.8492 ns | 54.2130 ns | 48.0584 ns |
| CalcHash_Sort | 10000 | 574,306.8290 ns | 2,864.5773 ns | 2,539.3732 ns |

##### LINQPad Code

#LINQPad optimize+

```
void Main()
{
    var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<HashCalcBenchmark>();
}

public interface IHasIntArray
{
    int[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Len : IHasIntArray
{
    public int[] Data { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Data?.Length ?? 0;
}

public class Xor : IHasIntArray
{
    public int[] Data { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        if (Data?.Length == 0)
            return 0;
            
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var e in Data)
            hash ^= e * 17;
            
        return hash;
    }
}


public class Sort : IHasIntArray
{
    public int[] Data { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (Data?.Length == 0)
            return 0;

        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var e in Data.OrderBy(i => i))
            hash ^= (hash * 397) ^ e;

        return hash;
    }
}

public class HashCalcBenchmark
{
    [Params(1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000)]
    public int NumArrayElements { get; set; }

    private Len len;
    private Xor xor;
    private Sort sort;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        len = new Len() { Data = Enumerable.Range(1, NumArrayElements).ToArray() };
        xor = new Xor() { Data = Enumerable.Range(1, NumArrayElements).ToArray() };
        sort = new Sort() { Data = Enumerable.Range(1, NumArrayElements).ToArray() };

    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int CalcHash_Len() => len.GetHashCode();

    [Benchmark]
    public int CalcHash_Xor() => xor.GetHashCode();

    [Benchmark]
    public int CalcHash_Sort() => sort.GetHashCode();
}
```

#### Checking for Set Membership

Here's a benchmark of an extreme example of finding an object in a hash set where there are zero hash collisions vs. where every hash is a collision. This is the worst possible case.

##### Key Results

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FindFoo | 98.66 ns | 11.20 ns | 33.01 ns | 84.15 ns |
| FindBar | 71,380.56 ns | 3,643.07 ns | 10,215.55 ns | 68,677.28 ns |

##### LINQPad Code

Add a NuGet reference to BenchmarkDotNet

```
#LINQPad optimize+

void Main()
{
    var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<HashCodeTester>();
}

public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id;
}

public class Bar : IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => 42;
}

public class HashCodeTester
{
    HashSet<Foo> foos;
    HashSet<Bar> bars;
    const int MAX = 10000;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        foos = Enumerable.Range(1, MAX).Select(n => new Foo() { Id = n }).ToHashSet();
        bars = Enumerable.Range(1, MAX).Select(n => new Bar() { Id = n }).ToHashSet();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool FindFoo() => ContainsById<Foo>(foos);

    [Benchmark]
    public bool FindBar() => ContainsById<Bar>(bars);

    bool ContainsById<T>(HashSet<T> set) where T : IHasId, new()
    {
        var find = new T() { Id = MAX / 2 };

        return set.Contains(find);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about the SequenceEqual. Doesn't it require same order, too? => Yes it does: https://dotnetfiddle.net/F0VShl But OP's requirement is that order of the clothesIds are irrelevant. Maybe that could be fixed.

Comment: The GetHashCode implementation is also order - aware, isn't it? That's why mine looked so awkward.

Comment: It's really awkward to generate an order-ignoring hash code for an array, unless you sort the arrays - that's going to change the complexity quite a lot!

Comment: @MatthewWatson You could just use a `HashSet`.

Comment: I suppose you could add all the hash codes (cast to uint) together into an unsigned long and then take the low 32 bits of that as the hash code. Adding is commutative, so that should work. (And for `int` you don't need to call GetHashCode(), you can just add the ints together.) Also it might work without casting to `uint`...

Comment: `&& new HashSet<int>(ClothesIds).SetEquals(other.ClothesIds)` also for the hashcode you can use `HashCode.Combine`

Comment: @Fildor Good call clarifying the requirements. I've updated my answer to reflect the OP's guidance.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Relying on the hash code for equality isn't a good idea because of the Birthday Problem. I've run into actual hash collisions even with 64-bit hashes and several hundred million inputs. 32-bit hash collisions are far more common than that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @Charlieface Good call with HashSet and SetEquals

Comment: @EricJ I didn't mean that you should use `GetHashCode()` for equality! Just that you could implement it using addition to obtain the same hash code regardless of the order of items in the array. You'd still need to implement `Equals()`.

Comment: Is this XORing `hash |= e * 17;`? Did you mean `hash ^= e * 17;`? Anyway what is the reason to multiply each value by 17?

Comment: Good catch with ^ typo. Reason for 17 (or any odd prime) is https://stackoverflow.com/a/299748/141172. Interesting side story about primes in nature https://www.mathnasium.com/ca/blog/20160422-math-in-nature-a-prime-life-cycle-for-periodical-cicadas

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Eric J. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77189168/2878550).

If the `ClothesIds` array contains **unique** ids only in any order, you could try the following:

1. Compare arrays using the [`Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) method.
2. Include in the `GetHashCode` only properties `HairId` and `MakeupId` (and possibly a size of the `ClothesIds` array).

The resulting code:

```
public class Look : IEquatable<Look>
{
    public int HairId { get; set; }
    public int MakeupId { get; set; }
    public int[] ClothesIds { get; set; }

    private static bool ArraysAreEqual(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a == null)
            return b == null;
        if (b == null)
            return false;

        return a.Length == b.Length && !a.Except(b).Any();
    }

    public bool Equals(Look other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return HairId == other.HairId &&
                MakeupId == other.MakeupId &&
                ArraysAreEqual(ClothesIds, other.ClothesIds);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is Look look) && Equals(look);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = HairId;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ MakeupId;
            if (ClothesIds != null)
            {
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ClothesIds.Length;
            }
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use this approach to involve array contents into hash computation:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hashCode = HairId;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ MakeupId;
        if (ClothesIds != null)
        {
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ClothesIds.Aggregate(0, (acc, n) => acc ^ n);
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Lambda `(acc, n) => acc + n` is an option also.

This approach doesn't depend on the order of array elements and is very fast in opposite to solutions with sorting. Disadvantage: it doesn't produce even results - no even distribution between buckets in a hash-based collection.
You should decide which approach better feeds your needs depending on your typical input data.

---

Usage:

```
Look a1 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 42, 1 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look a2 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 1, 42 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look b = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 99 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };
Look c = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { }, HairId = 8, MakeupId = 9 };

var looks = new Look[] { a1, a2, b, c };

var dupes = looks.GroupBy(look => look)
                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                        .SelectMany(group => group);
```

Result:
`dupes` contains elements `a1` and `a2`.

---

**Side note**
Be careful adding mutable objects into a hash-based collection. If an object is changed its hashcode is changed too, but a collection has no idea about that (and keeps the object in the original bucket). This will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: It seems that the code works; the only thing that is unclear to me is why we use only the length of the ClothesIds array in the GetHashCode? How does it handle your example when you have the same array of ints but in a different order?

Comment: @GrigoryZhadko It's not necessary to include all values in computation of the `GetHashCode`. The `GetHashCode` method intended to just speed up the lookup. And as stated in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode#remarks): _Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes._

Comment: In other words, collection first checks hashcodes for equality and then, if they are equal, calls the `Equals` method. Otherwise, if hashcodes are different, objects are definitely unequal and the `Equals` method is not called.

Comment: Try this object `Look a4 = new Look() { ClothesIds = new int[] { 1, 99 }, HairId = 2, MakeupId = 1 };` Your code says `a1.Equals(a4)` is false but also says they have the same hash code. That will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricJ. Undefined behavior is when `Equals` returns `true`, but hash codes are different.

Comment: True. I should have said that the behavior can cause some algorithms to perform poorly. You can choose `public override int GetHashCode() => 42;` but that will make HashSet and similar structures have less desirable big-O characteristics.

Comment: I created an absolute worst case benchmark illustrating the point above and added it to my answer.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree good hash is good. And fast hash is good too. The OP should find the balance. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I agree that has speed can also matter. If the int array typically only has a few elements sorting is very fast but still a lot slower than using the larray ength. At the end of the day, the best choice for hash method comes down to the shape of the data and what your program does with it. A good compromise between collision rate and hash speed could be to XOR the array elements together (without sorting, since that operation produces the same number regardless of element order).

Comment: @EricJ. Excellent! I've come to the same idea, and this is why I've edited my answer 5 hours ago. :)

Comment: I added some benchmarks for the various GetHashCode() implementations we've discussed.