Curious Java Hashcode Behaviour with Duplicate positive and negative doubles
I had a bit of a curious behaviour with negative and positive double value hashcodes I was not expecting. Essentially, if the same Double value appears twice in the hashcode function, if the sign of that Double changes (pos<->neg) the hashcode remains the same. E.g.:
public final int hashCode() {
    int result = ...
    result = 31 * result + netAmount.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + grossAmount.hashCode();
    ...
    return result;
}

Using jshell and looking at the binary for the hashcode, it makes sense that if you multiply by 2 you get the same value:
Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode() = 639279104
Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() = -1508204544

Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode() * 2 = 1278558208
Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() * 2 = 1278558208

Ok, that makes sense. But in my hashcode function I multiply by 31 after each step so that should prevent this? Perhaps not. Converting my hashcode function to a one liner:
31 * (123 + Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode()) + Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode() = -1017901339
31 * (123 + Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode()) + Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() = -1017901339

And if I do maths to that then we see this becomes:
31*123 + 32*Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode() = -1017901339
31*123 + 32*Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() = -1017901339

So 32 here has the same effect of bitshifting which means the positive double value ends up the same as the negative. Wild!
What should I be doing here in order to prevent these clashes? Just use 37 or some other number? Adding the hashcode of the signum of the double to the result?
edit: For clarification, the "one liner" is me trying to put together all the lines in the hashCode function. Essentially:
public final int hashCode() {
    int result = 123
    result = 31 * result + Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + Double.valueOf("460.4").hashCode();
    return result;
}

Do this for positive or negative double value of 460.4 and it has the same result.
final edit: I've been convinced not to use the default hashCode() implementation anyway and use something like Murmur hash. Not because of clashes but because I hadn't realised there are no guarantees that hashcode() will return the same value between application start-ups or even jvm version upgrades. Thanks for all the replies!

Two doubles consist of 128 bits. Comparing this to the 32 bits in an int, clashes are bound to occur. Do you mean you just want to avoid, specifically, the case where negative numbers clash with their positive counterpart?

Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() * 2L might help you

Anytime you multiply a power of 2 times an integer it is a bitshift.

You can also check what Double.hashCode does you might do something akin. It's not clear why you're using any magic numbers and multiplications.

I'd like to minimise collisions as much as possible but obviously nothing would be perfect. Multiplying properties hashcode by 31 seems to be the most popular way of doing this, I guess that just caught me out since 2 complete random doubles would be very unlikely to clash in their hashcodes but it wasn't apparent that could happen with the pos + neg of a double (since without *2 they just look like different number)

The "one lines" is trying to mimik the java logic, so:
public final int hashCode() {
    int result = ...
    result = 123 + netAmount.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + grossAmount.hashCode();
    ...
    return result;
}

I used 123 because it doesn't matter what that value is at that point


how often will you have two objects having the same value for grossAmount and netAmount and only differ in the sign and not in any other field? 2) How often does this object even appear as a key in a hash map? These two properties are actually indicating to me that it would be rather unlikely or at least, you should rethink the software design if objects with such properties appear as keys in hash maps.


@Holger the way I've understood the situation is not that gross and net amounts are equal and opposite. There is an object (possibly a POJO) that contains two fields (among others): netAmount and grossAmount. In a double-entry accounting system, amounts in a transaction sum to 0 (therefore have opposite signs): so you might have a POJO with a netAmount = 460.4, grossAmount = (let's say) 500.5, and another POJO with netAmount = -460.4, grossAmount = -500.5. Now if these two POJOs get inserted into a HashMap, they'll go in the same bucket. Claudio, can you confirm if I understood right?

@k314159 you are right, these numbers would also produce the same hash code. But they’d only go to the same bucket, if they are used as keys. Letting aside that this would raise my suspicion, such objects might end up at the same bucket anyway as the actual hash map would use far less bits than 32, depending on the table size.

@k314159 that is essentially it! However, this is a simplification of a different problem I didn't want to get into here, this hashcode function isn't there for the benefit of using a hashmap. Like I tried to say in a previous comment, I'm fine that 2 random double values have the same hashcode, but if 2 equal but opposite in sign doubles end up with the same hashcode that doesn't look random. It's not a problem, just unexpected.

It is quite curious that 31 is a popular choice of multiplier. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/299748/13963086 for some reasons. However, if you choose 37 instead, you won't get this problem.

You shouldn’t use these hash codes for anything other than “the benefit of using a hashmap”. They are not designed for other use cases. Even for the intended goal of serving a hash map Java’s hash codes do not always work well. That especially applies to doubles. E.g. initialize a map like HashMap<Double, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) map.put((double)i, null);, that is, default capacity and quite common values. How many bucket collisions do you expect? Half of all entries will end up in one bucket, for just ten entries total and the default capacity of 16…

Another thing worth noting is that 0.0 and -0.0 have different hashCodes, even though 0.0 == -0.0.

Also note that due to double using the 63rd bit as sign bit and how the hashcode for double values are computed, for any double value x Double.hashCode(x) == Double.hashCode(-x) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE and for any two double values x and y Double.hashCode(x) + Double.hashCode(y) == Double.hashCode(-x) + Double.hashCode(-y)

@Holger how do you test which bucket they go in? Just check hashCode%capacity? The Double hashcode seems to have changed since java 1.8

@matt by stopping in a debugger and looking into the array. The HashMap does not use the hash code directly, it applies a transformation before doing (effectively) % capacity. This transformation has changed in Java 8.

@k314159 The hashCode equals contract is not broken because Double a = 0.0; and Double b = -0.0 a and b have different hash codes and a != b. ie a.equals(b) is false.

@matt yes, but that's because a != b does reference equality. You mean a.equals(b) is false. That's correct, but it can be puzzling to beginners, because a < b, a > b, and a.equals(b) are all false, and a.compareTo(b) is 0.

@k314159 I had already corrected the comment. When you said 0.0 has a different hashcode than -0.0 its a bit confusing because double doesn't have hashcode. It is a primitive type.

You can use the static method Double.hashCode(double) to get the hashcode of a primitive.

So you're dealing with integer overflow here. hashCode returns an int:

public int hashCode()
Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()
The return type, int is 32-bits:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.SIZE
Even just multiplying your hashCode by 2 is causing an overflow (dropping the left-most bit AKA sign bit), making the two resulting values equal:
Double.valueOf(" 460.4").hashCode()     ->     00100110 00011010 10100000 00000000
Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode()     ->     10100110 00011010 10100000 00000000
Double.valueOf(" 460.4").hashCode() * 2 -> |0| 01001100 00110101 01000000 00000000
Double.valueOf("-460.4").hashCode() * 2 -> |1| 01001100 00110101 01000000 00000000

with the corresponding |0| and |1| indicating what bit has been dropped by the multiplication by 2 (which is essentially a single left shift because it is a power of 2).
Multiplication by 32 (again, a left shift of 5 because 32 is a power of 2), results in even more bits being dropped:
...(" 460.4").hashCode() * 32 -> |00100| 11000011 01010100 00000000 00000000
...("-460.4").hashCode() * 32 -> |10100| 11000011 01010100 00000000 00000000

Again, with the bits in the || being dropped.
I'm not sure where the 123 or the 31 come from in your examples but here are some suggestions:

maybe do your math using appropriate datatypes (eg. Double or Long) before applying hashCode
read and fully understand the hashCode contract at the link above (replicated below). The third point is very much of relevance here.


Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.


If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.


It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.


Thank's for the explanation, makes sense about the bitshifting. I understand hashcode clashes are fine, but a good hashcode tries to avoid that. If I often encounter objects where the only difference is in the signage, as my current hashcode function stands, I'll end up with frequent collisions. I found that out when I expected a hashcode to change when I manually made the double values negative but they didn't, even if the actual int values from a direct double.hashCode() are different.

I'm thinking your best bet for a "good" hashcode would be to do your math (eg. combining net and gross amount somehow) using appropriate datatypes (eg. Double)...that way you're not losing any bits of accuracy. Once you have that number (in Double form), rely on the Double hashCode() method to be "good" enough.

With a hashCode function like the one you have:
public final int hashCode() {
    int result = ...
    result = 31 * result + netAmount.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + grossAmount.hashCode();
    ...
    return result;
}

your issue will only occur when netAmount == grossAmount. As you have figured out, this is because the amount gets multiplied by 32, thereby bit-shifting the sign bit out of existence.
If you frequently have zero tax so that gross and net are the same, and having this kind of hashCode clash is an actual problem, then you might want to use 37 as a multiplier instead of 31. 37 is far enough away from a power of 2 that this issue is unlikely to occur.
By the way, one of the reasons 31 is often chosen is given by Joshua Bloch in "Effective Java, Second Edition":

The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even
and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as
multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using
a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. A nice property of 31 is
that the multiplication can be replaced by a shift and a subtraction
for better performance: 31 * i == (i << 5) - i. Modern VMs do this
sort of optimization automatically.


Of course the negative of some double value need not have the same hashCode.
That this happens is due to integer multiplication overflow and the fact that the floating point binary representation uses a sign bit (bit 63 in fact). Compare this with the two's complement of integral types where the other bits are different.
